How should I forward trace headers in distributed tracing with istio in a micronaut application
Our k8s cluster has istio distributed tracing enabled, I'm trying to get the traces for my micronaut application.
I can see in istio docs that we need to forward x3 headers and the x-request-id header and it was relatively easy for my springboot application, just adding
management:
  tracing:
    propagation:
      type: b3

would propagate my b3 headers from istio, but I'm unable to find a similar way of doing things with micronaut.
Currently I am storing the headers in a threadLocal in an HttpFilter and then using HttpClientFilter to add those headers to all outgoing requests, but I don't think this is the best way of doing things.
This is a micronaut 3.10 application.
Any insights highly appreciated, thanks.
